# How to get regularization parameter given by  = / in MAP

Tags: pattern-recognition

maximizing the posterior distribution is equivalent to minimizing the regularized sum-of-squares error function with a regularization parameter given by  = /.

Maximizing the posterior distribution is equivalent to minimizing the regularized sum-of-squares error function
 ̃()=  1/2 ∑*(=1)^▒{〖(〗*, )−_ }^2 +/2 ‖‖^2
where
‖‖^2  ≡^T = _0^2+*1^2+…+*^2
with a regularization parameter given by  = /.

Comment: Your question seems to be quite vague. It's not clear what your problem is, or what data you're working with. Do you have any code?

Comment: @Michelle it's not code but just a formula: Maximizing the posterior distribution is equivalent to minimizing the regularized sum-of-squares error function
 ̃()=  1/2 ∑_(=1)^▒{〖(〗_, )−_ }^2 +/2 ‖‖^2
where
‖‖^2  ≡^T = _0^2+_1^2+…+_^2
with a regularization parameter given by  = /.

Comment: What is your coding question?